# How to declare methods added to the prototype chain?

Tags: typescript

Given this

```
class GameActions {
  bootstrap() {
    return fetchGames().then((data: any) => {
      // error
      this.dispatch(data)
    })
  }
}

module.exports = alt.createActions(GameActions)
```

How do I inform typescript that `dispatch` is found in the prototype chain? `alt.createActions` adds `dispatch` through prototypical inheritance. Moreover, `alt` is an external flux library from npm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> alt.createActions(GameActions)

This is effectively a `mixin`. There isn't a good story about mixins in TypeScript at the moment. There is documentation of how to type it : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Mixins

You basically *declare* that these members exist but don't *define* them, i.e.:

```
class GameActions {
  bootstrap() {
    return fetchGames().then((data: any) => {
      this.dispatch(data)
    })
  }

  // Dispatchable:
  dispatch: Function;
}

module.exports = alt.createActions(GameActions)
```

Mixins are on the roadmap for 2.0 : http://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#20 Also you can start a discussion here : http://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues It would be great if you can come up with a proposal

Comment: That clears it up. Typescript needs a `becomes` keyword which means a it will implement some interface in the future. In my case, `class GameActions becomes ActionCreator`

Comment: Mixins are on the roadmap for 2.0 : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#20 Also you can start a discussion here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues It would be great if you can come up with a proposal.